# What does vorzeitig mean in the context of linguistics?

Tags: german-to-english

I came across the word 'vorzeitig' in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/23608227?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=martin&searchText=kummel&searchUri=/action/doBasicSearch?Query=martin+kummel&refreqid=search:82c466204f70eadc22b941a2ed7b11ee&seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents) ("Zur Verwendung des Perfektfutur im Altlatein") by Martin Kümmel. It's in the following sentence in section 3.1 on page 131:

> Wie schon bei Lindsay angedeutet, hat man schon lange vermutet, dass hier Reste einer älteren perfektiven (nicht perfektisch-vorzeitigen) Funktion vorliegen [...]

Comment: Could you please give more context?

Comment: @Matthias Okay, I've added a link to the article and the sentence it's from. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is very complicated stuff, so I'm not sure if I got it right, but here's how I understand it:

Short answer: it describes that something's in the past/preceding/previous to something else.

Long answer: this article is about the Old Latin usage of future perfect, which in Classical Latin means e.g. *"I will have completed"*. Apparently in Old Latin it was closer to future tense with perfective aspect (which afaik means basically, describing a one-time event, as opposed to imperfective aspect which denotes an indefinite stretch or repetition of an action), as in something like *"I will complete [at a certain point of time]"*.

So Classical Latin *"I will have completed"* describes a future action, but from a point of view in the even more distant future when it's already past. Thus, the action *precedes* the future scenario, and hence: "vorzeitig".

Finally, the "perfektisch" part marks a special aspect distinct from imperfective and perfective: it's also called resultative and focusses on the outcome of the action. I'm no linguist, but I think English *"I have completed"* fits that sense if the focus is on the fact that it is now completed. This is basically what's happening in Classical Latin future perfect: "in the future, it will have been completed".

I ask anyone who understands this all better than I do to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The passage means that Lindsay is making a reference to an "older" perfect tense, called the future perfect or "resultative" tense. This was contrasted to a "vorzeitig" or what would now call a [past perfect tense](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/), i.e.  where an action is one that started and ended in the past.

Comment: He's not talking about perfect tense or past perfect tense, but about perfective vs. "perfektisch" (resultative) *aspect*. The article is actually about Old Latin usage of the future perfect. I'm working on my own answer, but it may take a while.

Comment: @JimiJackson: Incorporated your insighful comment into a "rewritten" answer.